# Django Admin: Add User settings.Database Improperly configured

Tags: django, database, admin, router

Trying to Add a User by Django Admin App I get the following error:
[settings.DATABASE is improperly configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1h79.png)

My Databases are defined as:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['*****.routers.RouterDB',]
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'
    },    
    'helpdesk': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
)
```

And in my Router: So If the App is different from **** I get the 'helpdesk' DB that is the SQLite with Django Users.
The Mongo Database stores Users for another app that it's not to use Django App

```
from django.conf import settings

class RouterDB:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == '****':
            return 'default'
        return 'helpdesk'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == '****':
            return 'default'
        return 'helpdesk'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):

        if  obj1._meta.app_label == 'helpdesk' or \
            obj2._meta.app_label == 'helpdesk':
            return True
        if  obj1._meta.app_label == 'default' or \
            obj2._meta.app_label == 'default':
            return True
        return False

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):

        if app_label == 'helpdesk':
            return db == 'helpdesk'
        if app_label == '****':
            return db == 'default'
        return 'default'
```

Comment: indention is incorrect after `class RouterDB:` and it has no sub class between hooks or a __init__(self) function

Comment: @Lua Indention now is correct ( It was not correct just here, in code it is) and I don't understand the sub class and init part you told me.
In the examples I read about writting Database router are quite similar to mine.

Comment: i mean this with sub class: `class RouterDB(StandardDB):`

Comment: as an example..